# Collation not found when querying Photos SQLite database from C#

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am trying to run a select query against a Microsoft Win 10 database Photos SQLite database from C#. When I open the database with DB Browser for SQLite and browse the Item table it warns me that "A table in this database requires special collation function NoCaseUnicode that this application can't provide without further knowledge, and that bad thnigs may happen if I proceed." If I proceed, I can browse the table and filter its content. However, if I define a select query in the Execute SQL tab as follows

Select Item_FileName from Item where Item_FileName = '2.jpg';

I get 37 rows returned, all starting with the number 2, including the file 2.jpg. If I add 'Collate Binary' at the end of the query I get the expected single row returned.

A query involving a join between two tables using text fields from this database will run as expected in DB Browser for SQLite if 'Collate Binary' is appended to the query, but not if provided as the text of an SQLite command in C#, which is then executed. The message " Missing collation NoCaseUnicode" appears, even if 'Collate Binary' is appended. Presumably this is because the missing collation tables cannot be joined.

Is there way of collating the tables before performing the join to allow the query to be executed from C#?

Comment: Any luck with this? I did a little research, findings here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53935173/where-are-video-project-files-hidden-in-windows-photo-video-editor/55789958#55789958

Comment: No responses yet I'm afraid